# Memory leak reported by valgrind in composition

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, composition

I have a code which looks ok, but when I run `Valgrind` it is showing leak for fields which is allocated with new in `setNumberOfFields()` function. Here are excerpts of my code:

```
class arcField {
public:
    arcField();
    ~arcField();
};

arcField::arcField(){}

arcField::~arcField() {}

class arcRecord {
public:
    char       *recordType;                    
    int         numberOfFields;                 
    arcField   *fields;     

    arcRecord(){}
    ~arcRecord();
    void setNumberOfFields(int num);
};

arcRecord::~arcRecord() {
    if(fields) {
        delete [] fields;
    }
    fields = 0;
}

void arcRecord::setNumberOfFields(int num) {
       if(fields) {
       delete [] fields;
    }
    fields = 0;
    fields = new arcField[num];   // line number 335
}

int main() {
    int index = 1;
    arcRecord records[1];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    records[i].setNumberOfFields(index);  
    return 0;
}
```

> records[i].setNumberOfFields(tmp_int); // 940 line in valgrind.records is object of type arcRecord.

Valgrind Output:

```
==12647== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 33 of 642
==12647==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
**==12647==    by 0x705BC8: arcRecord::setNumberOfFields(int) (recordFF.cc:335)**
==12647==    by 0x707B2F: arcRecordList::loadConfigFile(cvConfig&) (recordFF.cc:940)
==12647==    by 0x7078C7: arcRecordList::loadConfigFile(char const*) (recordFF.cc:894)
==12647==    by 0x70771D: arcRecordList::arcRecordList(char const*) (recordFF.cc:883)
==12647==    by 0x5EE131: cvComericaArchive::cvComericaArchive() (cvComericaArcFuncs.cc:62)
==12647==    by 0x45581F: ArchInterface::ArchInterface(std::string const&, char const*) (ArchInterface.cc:115)
```

I am not sure why it is showing leak at line 335 whereas the destructor is called for the `arcField` object. I am not sure about this error. I guess the destructor of `arcRecord` is not getting called which is not deleting the `arcField` object.

Comment: `arcField::~arcField() { delete this; }` This looks like [Harakiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seppuku). I could imagine that Valgrind doesn't like it. This is what I saw at first glance. I would delete the `delete this;`, re-compile, and check whether it becomes better.

Comment: You destroy class in destructor and then try to delete it's fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am by far, not an expert in C++ / Valgrind, but I think you could have a memory leak if `arcRecord::setNumberOfFields` is called **multiple times**.

In such cases the pointer to the `arcField[]` stored in `fields` would simply be **replaced** by the new one pointing to the memory allocated by the `new arcField[num]`, **without the existing array in memory being actually deleted**.

The destructor would only be able to delete the **most recently allocated** `arcField[]`, (to which `fields` points) but not the ones allocated previously, to which you would have no pointer at all.

You should maybe initialise all your pointers to `0`:

```
char       *recordType = 0;
int         numberOfFields = 0;
arcField   *fields = 0;
```

and then in `arcRecord::setNumberOfFields` check if `fields` is set already and if yes, delete it before allocating.

```
void arcRecord::setNumberOfFields(int num) {
    if(fields) {
        delete [] fields;
    }
    fields = new arcField[num];
}
```

Comment: @Karan you should not update code in the question based on the answer, since other users can no longer understand the original issue.
The question should remain as it was so that **other Stackoverflow visitors can learn from it**.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Actually, I did wrong post which I wanted to delete,but as others invested time in it, so could not delete it. This was the original problem which I posted now. BTW it got resolved now by calling destructor explicitly at the end of the loop in which the function setNumberOfFields is called.